Why show like this error in python in create engine for access the sql db?
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:NO@localhost:3306/application')

df = pd.read_sql_table('customers',engine)
df

*RuntimeError:* 'cryptography' package is required for sha256_password or caching_sha2_password auth methods

How to solve this error?
I try to install the crytograher library,but its not working.

You need to install cryptography
pip install cryptography


To use “sha256_password” or “caching_sha2_password” for authenticate, you need to install additional dependency:

$ python3 -m pip install PyMySQL[rsa]

https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html
Also, make sure that your database mysql is started and working.
